# How to copy folder and rename it with current date and time in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I am trying to write a powershell script that copies my documents folder to a backups folder that I created in the same directory. 
my copy-item script looks like this:

```
copy-item C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ -destination C:\Users\Administrator\Backups\Backup1\
```

but instead of Backup1 I want it to say Backup-*CurrentDate-Time*

I know I need to use the get date function but I don't know how to implement it without getting an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Get-Date`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6) module and command substitution:

```
 copy-item .\documents\ -destination .\my-backup-$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss")
```